# Gorm doesn't create foreignkeys at many to many relationship

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I'm having a problem while trying to generate my DB using gorm.
all of the tables and the relationships(foreign-keys) are generated successfully except for many-to-many relationship, when I'm building the DB gorm does generate the association table but without foreign-keys.

I have the following structs: device and group. (group can have more then 1 device, and the same device can be in more then one group)

```
//Group group of devices
type Group struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name    string
        SVG     string
        Devices []*Device `gorm:"many2many:device_group;"`//association_foreignkey:id;foreignkey:id"` 
    }
```

//Device is a singe phisycal mesurment device

```
type Device struct {
    gorm.Model
    DeviceName string
    Svg        string
    IP         string
    LastActive time.Time
    MAC        string
    Version    string
    Groups     []*Group `gorm:"many2many:device_group;"`
}
```

add foreign key:

```
db.Model(device).AddForeignKey("id", "device_group(device_id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
db.Model(group).AddForeignKey("id", "device_group(group_id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
```

the add foreign key function is giving me the following error:

> [2020-01-28 11:53:11]  pq: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "device_group"

as you can see:  it's generating the device_group table but there are no foreign keys. 
I tried to play with field tags, tried to modify the AddForeignKey function or remove it but nothing seems to work.

[image]

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced keys must be primary keys, therefore you have to add the constraints the other way around. The following works for me with your code:

```
db.Table("device_group").AddForeignKey("device_id", "devices(id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
db.Table("device_group").AddForeignKey("group_id", "groups(id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
```

Comment: worked! and that look so obvious after your answer. 
hope that their documentation will be updated and that it will contain this example.